# Quotient of Noetherian (Artinian) ring is also Noetherian (Artinian)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

**Proposition 1:** Let $0\to M' \xrightarrow{f} M \xrightarrow{g} M''\to 0$ be an exact sequence of $A$-modules. Then:

i) $M$ is Noetherian **iff** $M'$ and $M''$ are Noetherian.

ii) $M$ is Artinian **iff** $M'$ and $M''$ are Artinian.

**Proposition 2:** Let $A$ be a Noetherian (Artinian), $I$ an ideal of $A$. Then $A/I$ is a Noetherian (Artinian) ring.

My question is the following: I know the proof of Proposition 1. How to use it in order to prove proposition 2?

I was trying to construct some examples of exact sequences but I failed to do it.

Comment: 2 is a special case of 1.

Comment: @MattSamuel, I know it but I am not able to come up with $M'$ and $M''$. Could you help, please?

Comment: I answered the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The exact sequence you want is
$$0\to I\to A\to A/I\to 0$$
$A$ is Noetherian or Artinian, hence so is $A/I$.

Comment: Nice! So you have used the $\Rightarrow$ direction of the Proposition 1. Right?

Comment: @ZFR That is correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will accept your answer in a few minutes! +1

Comment: @ZFR You're welcome.

Comment: This shows that $A/I$ is noetherian as an $A$-module. To show that  $A/I$ is a noetherian ring I need to show that it is noetherian as an $A/I$-module. 
I can provide al alternative proof of the latter, but it isn't clear (to me) how yours shows that $A/I$ is a noetherian ring.

Comment: @ラミタ Could you please show the alternative proof?

Comment: @kubo Every ring $R$ is noetherian as an $R$-module since it is finitely generated by $1_R$.